# Get the context of a object directly from the object itself

Tags: javascript, callback

I want to get the context of a object directly from the object itself.

For example, in the code below a callback function will be called with a `mousedown` event. It works correctly because I am binding the callback using `this.callback.bind(this))`.

As an interface, this is rather clunky. I would like to be able to simply pass `this.callback` and from within `MyClass2` figure out the context of the callback function and bind it on the receiving end. Is this possible?

```js
function MyClass1() {
  var _this = this;
  this.data = "Foo";
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  this.callback = function() {
    console.log("Callback: " + this.data);
  }
  var m2 = new MyClass2(div, this.callback.bind(this));

}

function MyClass2(div, callback) {
  var _this = this;

  // I'd like to bind callback to the context it had when it was passed here
  // e.g. this.callback = callback.bind(callback.originalContext);
  this.callback = callback;

  div.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    _this.mousedown.call(_this, e)
  });

  this.mousedown = function() {
    console.log("Mousedown");
    this.callback();
  }
}

var m1 = new MyClass1();
```

```html
<div id="div" style="background-color:azure; height:100%; width:100%">
  Click me
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just use your existing `_this` variable within the callback function, instead of `this`?

Comment: @nnnnnn - In this simplified example, yes - I can use `_this.data`. However, there are many times I'd like the context of the callback to be correctly bound.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Object.create for your MyClass1 to inheritate from MyClass2

```js
function MyClass1() {
  var _this = this;
  this.data = "Foo";
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var callback = function() {
    console.log("Callback: " + this.data);
  }
  MyClass2.call(this, div, callback);
}

function MyClass2(div, callback) {
  var _this = this;

  // I'd like to bind callback to the context it had when it was passed here
  // e.g. this.callback = callback.bind(callback.originalContext);
  this.callback = callback;

  div.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    _this.mousedown.call(_this, e)
  });

  this.mousedown = function() {
    console.log("Mousedown");
    this.callback();
  }
}

MyClass1.prototype = Object.create(MyClass2.prototype);
var m1 = new MyClass1();
```

```html
<div id="div" style="background-color:azure; height:100%; width:100%">
  Click me
</div>
```

Still, it seems a bit messy to play with those *this*, I'd try to avoid them (eg. using a factory pattern)